# "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, in-app-purchase, webhooks, google-play-console

I am seeking your assistance with a permissions issue I've encountered while working on my Android application, which utilizes Google Cloud services for real-time notifications through webhooks.The problem I'm facing is that I've set up webhooks per Google's documentation and assigned the owner permissions to my service account. Despite following the recommended procedures, I continue encountering the following error message: "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
All the available solutions suggesting to link the play console account to google account properly but the API access page has gone away. So if anyone encountered the same issue then please help.

I tried to implement webhooks for subscriptions and logs are getting accuretly on server but the details are not showing giving the error: "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.",
"errors": [
{
"domain": "androidpublisher",
"message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.",
"reason": "permissionDenied"
}
]
}
}

Comment: Enable the Google Play Developer API: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started#enable

Comment: @JohnHanley It is already enabled.

Comment: Edit your post and specify which services and how they are configured. Include details on authorization.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also getting the same error even pub/sub and service accounts are set up correctly.